# Question about the range of a norm preserving extension.

Tags: normed-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

Consider the subspace $Y =\{(x, x): x\in \mathbb{C}\}$ of the normed linear space $(\mathbb{C}^2, \|\ \|_{\infty})$.
If $\phi$ is a bounded linear functional on  $Y$,  defined by $\phi(x, x)=x$, then which one of the following sets is equal to
$$\big\{\psi(1, 0): \psi \ \text{is a norm preserving extension of}\ \phi\ \text{to}\ (\mathbb{C}^2, \|\ \|_{\infty})\big\}, \ \|(x, y)\|_{\infty}= \sup\{|x|, |y|\} $$

1. $\{1\}$
2. $[0, 1]$

My attempt: It can be easily shown that $\|\phi\|_{\infty}=1$. Since $\psi$ is a norm preserving extension, so $$\|\psi\|_{\infty}= \|\phi\|_{\infty}=1$$ Now as $\|(1, 0)\|_{\infty}= 1$, so this means $\psi(1, 0)\leq 1$. How to conclude further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any linear functional on $\mathbb C^2$ is of the form $\psi((x,y)) = a x + b y$ for some constants $a$ and $b$.  This is easily seen to have norm $|a|+|b|$.  Now you want 
$ax + b x = x$, i.e. $a+b=1$, and $|a|+|b|=1$, and you want to know what can $a$ be.  If $a \in [0,1]$, what should you take for $b$?